# How to insert an Outlook Signature into an email after attaching the ActiveWorkbook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro that begins with an Excel sheet, and will be sent through Outlook email to colleagues.

I've been trying to use the Ron de Bruin link to add a saved Signature to an Outlook email, but it's saying "File Not Found".
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm

-The Signature is not set as Default, because I have more than one Signature saved.

-The Path matches what it should be when I perform a `Debug.Print`

C:\Users\cday\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Inventory Report.htm

```vb
Sub Setup_Email()
    
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
    Dim StrSignature As String
    Dim SPath As String
    
    SPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\Inventory Report.htm"
    Debug.Print SPath
    
    StrSignature = Getsignature(SPath)
    
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .to = "People"
        .CC = "More People"
        .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Name
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .HTMLBody = StrSignature
    End With
        
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
    
Function Getsignature(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2) **"File Not Found"**
    
    Getsignature = ts.readall
    
    ts.Close
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I relooked at my macro as was missing the Call - `GetBroiler` Function:

```
Sub Setup_Email()

    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\Inventory Report.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .Display
        .to = "People"
        .CC = "More People"
        .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Name
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .HTMLBody = Signature
    End With
    
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually see the signature file with that name in Windows Explorer?
Keep in mind that "`Signatures`" folder name is localized. The actual folder name is stored in the `Signatures` value at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Common\General
```

Comment: Under: `C:\Users\cday\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures`, I see `Inventory Report.htm`, `Inventory Report.rtf`, and `Inventory Report.txt`.